# How to get the immediate parent element containing a character found with :contains in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, contains

I need to find certain characters and strip them out.  I know I can do this with

```
$('.identifiable-selector:contains("x")').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("x").join(""));
});
```

however the character may appear in a few different places, so I have to choose a starting point for the `:contains` that is fairly high in the hierarchy.  What I want to do is start the `:contains` search high enough that I know I will find the character wherever it is, but I only want to do the stripping / HTML rewriting at the highest level necessary (meaning, somewhere lower than where I start my search).

For instance, in this case

```
<div class='identifiable-selector'>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    content content x content
                    <div>
                        <div>content x content</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

I need to start my search at the `.identifiable-selector` level, but I want to get ahold of the `td` that is the highest level of elements that actually contain `x` so that I only have to rewrite that HTML.

How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: You missed last close `)` in your  `$(this).html($(this).html().split("x").join(""))`;

Comment: Thanks @JqueryKing, I made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to eliminate the 'x' instances within the <td> element's text, and not any enclosed HTML elements (like the <div> in your example), you would check to see if you have a TEXT_NODE and then do the replace.

```
$('.identifiable-selector td:contains("x")').contents().each(function () {
    var td = $(this);
    if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
    {
        // alert('Old text:' + $(this).text());
        var newText = $(this).text().split("x").join("");
        //alert("New text:" + newText);     // Uncomment and see in action
        this.textContent = newText;

    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/svs0pc0q/ for this in action.

If you want everything, including all enclosed elements that have text that contains an 'x', then just eliminate the TEXT_NODE check.